# Method definition and objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods, runtime

Do class objects in Java have their own copy of methods or is it limited to the class definition. If the latter is true then how do objects, in a mult-threaded environment gets access to the method instructions.

Wanted to know how method calls work in mult-threaded environment if the same method is being called for the objects of the same class.

Tried searching on Google, chatgpt etc. but couldn't get an accurate answer on this works.

Comment: "Do class objects in Java have their own copy of methods" - No.   Assuming I correctly understand what you mean by "class objects" and "own copy".

Comment: "Wanted to know how method calls work in mult-threaded environment if the same method is being called for the objects of the same class." - It is exactly same as in the single-threaded case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "if the same method is being called for the objects of the same class" -- what is the problem with that? The method's code is not being changed, it is only read - there should be no problem if multiple threads are reading the same memory

Comment: Strictly speaking it’s implementation dependent. But no one in their right mind would make an implementation where each object and/or each thread has its own copy of the byte code of the methods. (It’s a good question because *conceptually* each object has all the methods declared in the class.)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Computer memory within a single running program is one big pool. And all your code resides within a single copy. No, your individual threads do not get their own copies. For that matter, they don't get their own copies of your data, either, unless you create new objects within the thread and don't let anyone else have them.

It's safe, though, because the code is static and isn't going to get modified. Variables your methods use will be unique and safe, though. So if you do this:

```
public void foo() {
    int value = 10;
}
```

Then everyone running foo will have their own version of value. For that matter, if foo recurses (calls itself), then you now have two copies of value -- one in the first invocation and a different one in the second.